# How to iterate through Active Records relation and find information based on it in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say I have three classes. Users, UserOrganisation, Organisations.

Users have their userids, encrypted passwords etc.

UserOrganisation have organisationid as foreign key, userid also as foreign key. Organisations have id, organisation name, address etc.

Say i have a variable which has all the UserOrganisation's data like this.

```
@user = User.where(email: "test@test.com")

@userOrganisation = @user.userOrganisation
```

How do I get the Organisation ID from @userOrganisation and get the name from Organisation table using the ID?

I want to render the organisation name as JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_organizations
  has_many :organizations, through: :user_organizations
end

# rails g model user_organization user:belongs_to organization:belongs_to
class UserOrganization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :organization
end

class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_organizations
  has_many :organizations, through: :user_organizations
end
```

This creates [a many to many association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) between `User` and `Organization` with `user_organizations` as the join table. Note that the columns, method names and associations (pretty much everything except classes) should be `snake_case`.

To get the organizations a user is the member of you can use:

```
user.organisations
```

Rails will automatically join the `user_organizations` table for you.

If you want an array containing the id and name of each organization you would do:

```
user.organisations.pluck(:id, :name)
```

Comment: I would recommend you read the [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) and spellcheck your questions before you post them.

Comment: Thats such a perfect answer. Thanks. I am reading the ruby style guide now. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

`@userOrganisation.reflections['assigned_to'].options[:foreign_key]`

This should get the id if you do want the id, but as one comment mentions, you should setup correct associations and handle it that way